# Substitute, deparse in dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

There seems to be a difference as to where the following function is called from, but I am not getting it.

Calling this

```
give_names = function(...) {
   sapply(substitute(list(...))[-1], deparse)
}
```

like that

```
paste(give_names(var, sd), collapse = ", ")
#[1] "var, sd"
```

is very different from calling it like that:

```
d = dplyr::mutate(data.frame(1), x = paste(give_names(var, sd), collapse = ","))
d[, "x"]
#[1] "c(\"function (x, y = NULL, na.rm = FALSE, use) \", \"{\", \"    if (missing(use
# (I truncated the output, its just function definitions but not names.)
```

Why does `mutate` return different results?

Comment: This doesn't work with dplyr .5, r 3.2.4, error: no applicable method for 'as_data_frame' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: This is not a pipe problem, it's a `mutate` bug, which you can check by doing the same thing without a pipe. For some reason `mutate` evaluates all of the functions (or maybe everything?) in the expression (instead of eval'ing the whole thing as one expression), and since `var` and `sd` are function names, they get evaluated before `give_names` is called, which then gets the function definitions as input, resulting in garbage output.

Comment: @eddi thanks for the info! I finally got around to confirm it's `mutate` thing and updated the question accordingly. Is there anything that can be done, like a workaround?

Comment: @jakub I don't know what exactly you want. Base R clearly works - is that not a workaround? So does e.g. `data.table`: `data.table(1)[, x := paste(give_names(var, sd), collapse = ",")][]`. But what tool you choose will depend on what you're doing.

Comment: @eddi I meant using `mutate`, but its probably much easier to just do this in base R. Anyway, if you care to make your previous comment about mutate into an answer, I'll accept it (since that is what the question originally asks).

Comment: I don't think it qualifies as an answer tbh. More details are needed which I'm not motivated to figure out.